# Performing Mesh Analysis on h-parameter transistor models

Tags: circuit-analysis

So I'm fairly comfortable with Mesh and Nodal analysis with numerical values, but I am having problems solving this circuit involving an alternative h-parameter model of a transistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2M80n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First as a note, I could not incorporate subscripts in the editor. Everything including hi, hr, v2 etc is subscripted at the second digit.

The question is to find the voltage gain (v1/v2) and the resistance (Req =v1/i1)

So I have establashed two meshes **I1** and **I2.** These meshes are in the clockwise direction of both loops:

**I1**

-V1 + hi(i1) + hr • v2 = 0

**I2**

(hf/ho)•i1 + (1/ho)i2 + v2 = 0

So I simply solve for V1 and V2 on each mesh and then get the answer

**V1** = i1•hi + hr•v2

**V2** = -(hf/ho)•i1 - (1/ho)i2

So V1/V2 would simply be

-(i1•hi + hr•v2)/((hf/ho)•i1 - (1/ho)i2)

This doesn't really help me on finding Req, and I think I need more simplification. Am I on the right track with this problem? What am I missing to solve this problem properly? Thanks

Comment: Just for future reference, and it doesn't really matter if you do this in your question... just letting you know about MathJax. Subscripts like \$h_o\$ <--- can be written as `\$h_o\$`... or if there's more than one character in the subscript, like \$h_{o1}\$ can be written as `\$h_{o1}\$`.

Comment: Also, is (hf/h0)i1 supposed to be a dependent **current source**, instead of a dependent voltage source?

Comment: That's how it was written but I guess that does turn it into a dependent current source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a loading resistor That connects I2 to V2 by Ohms law. That's your missing equation. You can substitute I2 = -V2/RL. Now you have 2 equations still left which have variables V1, I1 and V2. Eliminate I1 and you get finally the wanted ratio of V2 and V1.

(BTW: We others like to see V2/V1 named as the voltage gain, not V1/V2)

As well you can eliminate V2 and get V1/I1 which was the other wanted ratio.